# Override default algorithm in RSA object to support OaepSHA256 padding

Tags: c#, rsa, sha256, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Creating `RSA` or `RSACryptoServiceProvider` object in .Net 4.6 is defaulting `KeyExchangeAlgorithm` `RSA-PKCS1-KeyEx` which supports only `OaepSHA1` padding.

Getting "Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm" on trying to use other padding like "OaepSHA256".

Is there a way to override algorithm in RSA object to an algorithm that supports this padding to make it supportive for all paddings.

[image]

**UPDATE**
RSACng works. In my scenario I am using containerkey to store private key in the machine using RSACryptoServiceProvider to retrieve private key when required using containerkey name. As a workaround to use RSACng I am importing properties exporting from RSACryptoServiceProvider object like shown below. Is there a better way to do this?

```
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams))
            {
                using(var rsaCng = new RSACng())
                {
                    rsaCng.ImportParameters(rsa.ExportParameters(true));

                    decryptedResult = rsaCng.Decrypt(encryotedText, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256)
                }
            }
```

Comment: "in .Net 6.0" - there is no .NET 6.0. Please clarify what platform you're targeting.

Comment: The KeyExchangeAlgorithm property has no real meaning, you should ignore it. But you need to use RSACng, not RSACryptoServiceProvider.

Comment: Sorry for the typo its .NET 4.6

Comment: Thanks RSACng works. In my scenario I am using containerkey to store private key in the machine using RSACryptoServiceProvider to retrieve private key when required using containerkey name. As a workaround to use RSACng I am importing properties exporting from RSACryptoServiceProvider object does it sounds fine. Is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks @Dai RSACng works. Any comments on the workaround provided in update

Comment: Thanks @bartonjs RSACng works. Any comments on the workaround provided in update

Comment: @TryingStuff that’s better asked as a different question. If you’re trying to open an existing CAPI key, show building up the CspParameters, there’s probably a much more direct way.

Answer (score 3):

`RSA` supports `OaepSHA256` in .NET Framework since .NET Framework 4.6 and in .NET Core since 1.0 (as well as `OaepSHA1`, `OaepSHA256`, `OaepSHA384`, `OaepSHA512` and the standard for PKCS#1, [see the documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsaencryptionpadding?view=netframework-4.8)).

As for support in older versions of .NET Framework - I don't believe it's possible because the Cryptography API treats cryptographic algorithm implementations as opaque black-boxes without much room for extensibility (i.e. you can't really subclass an existing implementation, but you can reimplement your own easily enough). I note this is partly because the API simply wraps Windows' built-in crypto functionality which is opaque anyway (like how `System.Drawing` wraps GDI without much room for extension there either).

As for the "Specified padding mode is not valid for this algorithm" error - the issue is you're using `RSACryptoServiceProvider` instead of `RSACng`. You should prefer the Cryptographic-Next-Generation (`Cng`) implementations over `CryptoServiceProvider` implementations, [see this article for more details](https://dusted.codes/how-to-use-rsa-in-dotnet-rsacryptoserviceprovider-vs-rsacng-and-good-practise-patterns).

If you're targeting .NET Framework 4.6 or later, or .NET Core 1.0 or later, you can use it like so:

```
using Sytem.Security.Cryptography;

Byte[] inputPlaintext = ...
RSAEncryptionPadding oaepsha256 = RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256;
using( RSA rsaImpl = new RSACng() )
{
    Byte[] ciphertext = rsaImpl.Encrypt( inputPlaintext, oaepsha256 );
}
```